# OnServiceConnected not getting called

Tags: android, android-service

I referred to the following questions already but could not find an answer:

- [Can't get service object (onServiceConnected never called)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008601/cant-get-service-object-onserviceconnected-never-called),
- [onServiceConnected not getting called , getting a null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844920/onserviceconnected-not-getting-called-getting-a-null-pointer-exception), and
- [onServiceConnected never called after bindService method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486692/onserviceconnected-never-called-after-bindservice-method)

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PodService.class);
        context.bindService(intent, mPodServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }




    private ServiceConnection mPodServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Pod: Service Connected");
                  mPodService = IPodService.Stub.asInterface(service); //here i am getting NullPointerException
                }
        }
```

and My service class contains nothing, only this much, i have shown it bellow

```
public class PodService extends Service {
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("bound", "bound");
        return null;
    }

 static class PodSeviceStub extends IPodService.Stub {

//here i implemented unimplemented methods

    }
}
```

But in lolcat i am getting only "`bound`" message from onBind() function, but not printing "`Pod: Service Connected`", means service is started successfully.
and in lolcat i am getting `NullPointerException` and also mentioned in manifest file too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote the service class so that onBind() returns IBinder as follwos.

```
public class PodService extends Service {
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        Log.d("bound", "bound");
        return mBinder; // returns IBinder object
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new PodSeviceStub(this);

 static class PodSeviceStub extends IPodService.Stub {

         WeakReference<PodService> mService;

        public PodSeviceStub(PodService service) {// added a constructor for Stub here
            mService = new WeakReference<PodService>(service);
        }
//here i implemented unimplemented methods

    }
}
```

and now it works.

Comment: please explain your solution !!

Comment: I rewrote the service class so that onBind() returns IBinder